# How to create a bounded power series

Tags: power-series, bounded-variation

Let's say I have a power series like $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^{b_n}$
For example, with $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}$ and $b_n=2n+1$, it's the sine function so it's bounded.

If I have to choose $a_n$ and $b_n$, what conditions should I have on them to be sure the power series will be bounded (at least in its convergence interval) ? (I don't even know if it's possible to find such conditions, but my final goal would be to get a non-periodic bounded power series or polynomial, so if you have another idea, I'll take it)

Comment: take a look at entire functions at wikipedia.org

Comment: @mike they say that any entire function can be developed in a power series that converges, but if I understand well, in order to find $a_n$, I would need to find an entire function and know all of its derivatives, which seems a bit too complicated (I didn't mention that I need to be able to make this function in programming after I found it)

Comment: For entire functions, $b_n=n$, so the second equation on that page $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n|^{1/n}=0$ determines the forms for $a_n$.  This is of course only part of the answer you are seeking for.